# What happens to Huffman in this case (compressing image)

Tags: image-processing, reverse-engineering, huffman-code, electronic-signature

I was wondering , what happens to Huffman coding when the pixels are similar, so basically Huffman uses probability of each symbol and worth through it.

what happens if the image was like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6

1 2 3 4 5 6

1 2 3 4 5 6

ect.
does Huffman coding fails here?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't fail at all. If your images were stored with eight bits per pixel, now they will be stored with, on average, 2.67 bits per pixel. Compressed by a factor of three.

While the symbols all have equal probability, there are only six of them. That permits Huffman coding to use fewer bits per symbol.